# Performance degradation after optimizing SQL query with additional fields in BigQuery

Tags: sql, performance, google-bigquery

I recently optimized a two-step SQL process in BigQuery to enhance performance. The initial step involves selecting 10 fields from table T1 (containing billions of records) and performing left joins with tables T2 and T3 to retrieve one field from each. In the second step, the intermediate table from the first step is left joined with table T4 (with as many records as T1) to fetch an additional 20 fields. Since these 20 fields are also present in T1, I refined the process by directly selecting all necessary fields from T1 in the first step, eliminating the need for the left join with T4 in the second step. This modification was expected to significantly improve overall performance.

However, the issue now is that the first step has become excessively slow. Surprisingly, the slot time has increased from 9 hours to 9 days.

Even though the execution graphs for both scenarios appear almost identical in their steps, the optimized version performs significantly worse.
The slot time required for the input step of the first phase has increased, which is expected as more fields from T1 are now selected. However, the number of fields has only tripled, whereas the time has increased between 10 and 15 times.
Furthermore, the join operations between T1 and T2, and T1 and T3 now take much longer, despite no changes to the join clauses or where filters in the query. This unexpected behavior makes it challenging to plan efficient queries in BigQuery.

I need assistance in understanding what to investigate, as such behavior complicates the planning of performant queries in BigQuery. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: here are examples of the 2 versions for the first step

```
-- STEP_1 with fewer fields (but this required a 2nd step with a expensive left join to T4)

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `INTERMEDIATE_TABLE_STEP_1_TEST_1`
CLUSTER BY field1,field3,field5,field6
OPTIONS (
 expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
)
AS (
SELECT
   a.key,
   a.field1,
   CASE WHEN b.field2 IS NOT NULL THEN b.field2
        ELSE a.field3 END AS field3,
   a.field4,
   a.field5,
   a.field6,
   a.field7 as field7,
   a.field8,
   a.field9,
   CASE WHEN a.field10 <> 'LOW' OR a.field8 = 'asdasd' THEN 'cas1' ELSE 'cas2' END AS field10,
   CASE WHEN a.field11='field11' AND a.field12 LIKE 'field12%' AND a.field13 = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS field13,
   CASE WHEN pape.key IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS field14
FROM `TABLE_1` a
LEFT JOIN `TABLE_2` b ON a.key = b.key
LEFT JOIN `TABLE_3` pape ON pape.key = a.key
WHERE A.field11 = 'filter_1'
   AND a.date_filter >= (DATE_ADD((CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE)+1),INTERVAL -5 MONTH))
);


-- STEP_1 with more fields (avoids steps 2 completely, but this step performs terribly bad)
Query
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `INTERMEDIATE_TABLE_STEP_1_TEST_2`
OPTIONS (
 expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
)
AS (
SELECT
   SPLIT(SPLIT(a.field15, ',') [OFFSET(2)],':')[OFFSET(1)] AS field15,
   SPLIT(SPLIT(a.field15, ',') [OFFSET(1)],':')[OFFSET(1)] AS field15bis,
   Extract(HOUR From a.dttm_field) AS hora,
      a.key,
      a.field16,
      a.field17,
      a.field18,
   CASE WHEN LENGTH(CAST(a.field19 AS STRING)) = 1 THEN
             a.field20||"_000"||a.field19
        WHEN LENGTH(CAST(a.field19 AS STRING)) = 2 THEN
             a.field20||"_00"||a.field19   
        WHEN LENGTH(CAST(a.field19 AS STRING)) = 3 THEN
             a.field20||"_0"||a.field19
        ELSE a.field20||"_"||a.field19 END AS field19,
      a.field20,
      a.field21,
      a.date_filter,
      a.field22,
      a.field23,
      a.field24,
      a.field25,
      a.field26,
      a.field27,
      a.field28,
      a.field29,
      a.field30,
      a.field31,
      a.field4 AS field4b,
      a.field4,
      a.field32,
   a.field1,
      a.field6,
   a.field5,
      a.field33,  
      a.field19,
      JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(field34, '$.f1.f2') AS f1f2,
      SUBSTR(field35,2,LENGTH(field35)-2) AS field35,
   CASE WHEN a.field10 <> 'LOW' OR a.field8 = 'asdasd' THEN 'cas1' ELSE 'cas2' END AS field10,
   CASE WHEN a.field11='field11' AND a.field12 LIKE 'field12%' AND a.field13 = TRUE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS field13,
   CASE WHEN pape.key IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS field14,
   'null' as nullf,
   CASE WHEN b.field2 IS NOT NULL THEN b.field2
        ELSE a.field3 END AS field3,
   a.field7 AS fieled7,
   a.field8,
   a.field9,
   a.field36 AS field36
from `TABLE_1` a
LEFT JOIN `TABLE_3` pape ON pape.key = a.key
LEFT JOIN `TABLE_2` b ON a.key = b.key


WHERE 1=1
    AND A.field11 = 'filter_1'
    AND a.date_filter >= (DATE_ADD((CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE)+1),INTERVAL -5 MONTH))
);
```

[STEP 1-few fields: Execution Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Vdv.png)

[STEP 1-few fields: Graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJC5M.png)

[STEP 1-many fields: Execution Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlMvv.png)

[STEP 1-many fields: Graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhElL.png)

Comment: Please update your question with both queries and their EXPLAIN PLANS

Comment: Added queries, execution details a execution graphs for the 2 queries @NickW

Comment: Add everything as editable text, appropriately formatted, not as (links to) images

Comment: One thing to try is just stepping through your new field additions one by one and see where things go haywire. Like JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR is a deprecated function per the documentation, try commenting that out to try and isolate.

Comment: There are 2 warning icons (!) in the second graph - do those link to some detail;? if so, what do they indicate? see https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhElL.png

Comment: The second "execution details" image https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlMvv.png shows **5.15TB**  "bytes volcados al disco" translated as "**bytes dumped to disk**"  - that is a lot of disc activity

Comment: @AdrianMaxwell, the warning icons detail are: "This stage had slot containment. This stage significantly exceeded the available memory shuffle capacity."

Comment: I would return to the original approach and see if that returns to the original performance. (If not what else may have changed in the environment?) Then re-consider each of the columns not included in the original approach. e.g. are any of these "huge"? (video/image/blob) could the JSON column be a cause of slowness - looks for anything that might cause the excessive disc activity of the second approach. I don't think we can propose anything specific as we don't have any way to replicate your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AdrianMaxwell. Following Error_2646 idea, and yours, I stepped through all of the fields, and found a huge one as the main offender for the performance degradation. It still makes no sense that selecting this field from T1 is slower than making a left join and selecting it in the next step from T4. It also makes no sense that the joins between T1, T2 and T3 are so slow now that I select more fields from T1... The join operation remains the same. There is some obscure magic that BQ is trying to do that kills performance, and I cant pinpoint what it is...

Comment: If the initial part of the query is scanning every row of T1 then it makes absolute sense that including the huge field at that point could cause massive disk activity. You might find it better to go in the other direction. Include ONLY the columns needed for the where clause and and INNER joins in the initial query (absolutely nothing more than those columns!). Once you have arrived that the minimum filtered set to meet where clause conditions and necessary joins for the where clause, only then, using an INNER  join bring in the columns needed from T1. I will suggest a query below:

Answer (score 0):

Either as a "derived table" or, as a CTE, filter the main table first, then access the necessary (and only necessary) extra fields. A CTE can in some systems have slight beneficial performance impacts (not sure if this is the case for you) e.g. as a CTE:

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT tKEY -- no more then this, just the bare minimum
    FROM `TABLE_1`
    WHERE field11 = 'filter_1'
    AND date_filter >= (DATE_ADD((CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) + 1), INTERVAL - 5 MONTH))
    )

-- later:
INNER JOIN `TABLE_1` a ON t1.key = a.key
```

Or, using a "derived table":

```
SELECT
      SPLIT(SPLIT(a.field15, ',') [OFFSET(2)], ':') [OFFSET(1)] AS field15
    , SPLIT(SPLIT(a.field15, ',') [OFFSET(1)], ':') [OFFSET(1)] AS field15bis
    , Extract(HOUR FROM a.dttm_field) AS hora
    , a.KEY
    , a.field16
    , a.field17
    , a.field18
    , CASE
            WHEN LENGTH(CAST(a.field19 AS STRING)) = 1 THEN a.field20 || "_000" || a.field19 
            WHEN LENGTH(CAST(a.field19 AS STRING)) = 2 THEN a.field20 || "_00" || a.field19 
            WHEN LENGTH(CAST(a.field19 AS STRING)) = 3 THEN a.field20 || "_0" || a.field19 
            ELSE a.field20 || "_" || a.field19 
        END AS field19
    , a.field20
    , a.field21
    , a.date_filter
    , a.field22
    , a.field23
    , a.field24
    , a.field25
    , a.field26
    , a.field27
    , a.field28
    , a.field29
    , a.field30
    , a.field31
    , a.field4 AS field4b
    , a.field4
    , a.field32
    , a.field1
    , a.field6
    , a.field5
    , a.field33
    , a.field19
    , JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(field34, '$.f1.f2') AS f1f2
    , SUBSTR(field35, 2, LENGTH(field35) - 2) AS field35
    , CASE
            WHEN a.field10 <> 'LOW' OR a.field8 = 'asdasd' THEN 'cas1' 
            ELSE 'cas2'
      END AS field10
    , CASE
        WHEN a.field11 = 'field11' AND a.field12 LIKE 'field12%' AND a.field13 = TRUE THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
      END AS field13
    , CASE 
            WHEN pape.KEY IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
       END AS field14
    , 'null' AS nullf
    , CASE 
        WHEN b.field2 IS NOT NULL THEN b.field2 
        ELSE a.field3 
      END AS field3
    , a.field7 AS fieled7
    , a.field8
    , a.field9
    , a.field36 AS field36
FROM (
    SELECT t1.KEY
    FROM `TABLE_1`
    WHERE field11 = 'filter_1'
    AND date_filter >= (DATE_ADD((CURRENT_DATE - EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURRENT_DATE) + 1), INTERVAL - 5 MONTH))
    ) AS t1
INNER JOIN `TABLE_1` a ON t1.key = a.key
LEFT JOIN `TABLE_3` pape ON pape.KEY = a.KEY
LEFT JOIN `TABLE_2` b ON a.KEY = b.KEY
```

I hope it is also evident that an index on date_filter should help performance (and I'm assuming "key" is suitably indexed as well).

Comment: I cannot overstress that you should only include the columns you really truly need. It is excessive disc activity that is causing slowness, so take every action possible to avoid that.

Comment: try this: `DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, MONTH), INTERVAL - 5 MONTH)`

Comment: Thank you very much @Adrian for the help. I tried this approach, but it significantly worsened the perfomance. I had to stop it at 29 days of slot time (vs 9 days of original problematic query). For me, this do make sense, because the inner join on T1 is really expensive. For the rest, i do have cluster on key, and partition on date_filter_field.

Comment: A cte on "key" made it worse? Very Weird! What data type is that column?

Comment: The key es numeric type. I dont think the CTE is the problem, but the self Inner Join with the full table.

Comment: Remove all columns except key from the first select. If the table is indexed on key then the inner join by itself should not be the problem, it is  far more likely it is the disc activity to get the other columns that is the problem.